# Invariance of the rank of the trace of Riemannian curvature under a change of frame

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let 
$$
R=\begin{pmatrix} R_{11} & ... & R_{1n} \\ &...\\  
R_{n1} &...&  R_{nn} \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $R_{ikjl}$ is curvature tensor of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and $R_{ij}=g^{kl}R_{ikjl}$. How to show the rank of $R$ is invariant under changing frame?  I just guessed the result, I really don't know how to start to prove it .

Comment: This is just a consequence of the linear algebra fact that the rank of a symmetric bilinear form is independent of basis.

Comment: @Travis   which book about linear algebra is suitable for  this question ?

Comment: Probably any book on abstract linear algebra would do. But this fact is almost immediate: Under a change of basis (with change-of-basis matrix $P$), the matrix representation $[R]$ of a bilinear form transforms as $[R] \mapsto P^T [R] P$. Since $P$ is invertible, it has full rank (and hence so does $P^T$), so $\operatorname{rank} [R] = \operatorname{rank} (P^T [R] P)$.

Comment: @Travis  Thanks ,your answer is easy to understand.

Comment: You're welcome. Since this essentially answers your question, I've rewritten my comment as a proper answer.

Comment: As you probably know, the tensor $R_{ij}$ is usually called the *Ricci curvature* of $g$.

Comment: @Travis  I think it is Ricci tensor ,in my book ,Ricci curvature is $Ric(e_i)=R_{ii}=\sum\limits_k R_{ikik}$

Comment: That definition makes $Ric$ a quadratic form (at each tangent space), which is not usage I've seen before. Even if one uses that definition, $R_{ij}$ is the bilinear form one gets by polarizing that quadratic form. NB the summation formula only holds in orthonormal bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a question of linear algebra. In fact, the rank of any bilinear form is independent of basis: Under a change of basis (with change-of-basis matrix $P$), the matrix representation $[R]$ of a bilinear form $R$ transforms as $$[R] \mapsto P^T [R] P.$$ Since $P$ is invertible, it has full rank (and hence so does $P^T$), so the matrix representations of $R$ w.r.t. the two bases satisfy $$\operatorname{rank} [R] = \operatorname{rank} (P^T [R] P)$$
as claimed.